# spanlabel component does not display all the text

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to show text with SpanLabel, but this component does not display all the text if there is line break. I then try it with TextArea and Label UIID, but the result is the same. Can someone help me on this issue? Thanks

Comment: You need to include a screenshot and the way you used the API. I would suggest using the Component Inspector as well to view the position/size of the component. I'm guessing that the layout in which the component was placed didn't provide it enough space but there are other options such as font size/padding differences between states etc.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, I face the same issue. My code is below ....

Comment: You added a question, not an answer. If you set preferred width you don't leave room for the span label to grow. Margin in a dialog won't work as it's used to position the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem here. I use the SpanLabel inside a Dialog and the last one or two lines are always cut off.

It only happens when I use the `setPreferredW` property:

```
 spanLabelDialog.setPreferredW(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()-300);
```

Is this intended?

Somehow the `setMargin` property doesn't work for the dialog, neither hard-coded, nor in CSS.

Here is my code:

```
private void dialolg () {

    String longText = "'There should be the whole text displayed here, but it seems the last one or two lines always get cut off'";

    spanLabelDialog.setText(longText);
    dialogExplain.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, spanLabelDialog);

    spanLabelDialog.setUIID("SpanLabelDialog");
    spanLabelDialog.setTextUIID("SpanLabelDialog");

    spanLabelDialog.setPreferredW(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()-300);

    dialogExplain.show();

}
```

[image]